# two similar code, one work, one randomly timeout. Why?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, timeout

Here is the base code regarding the two examples :

```
private void AsyncTest()
{   
    //GetServiceObject Will add custom bindings and more..
    Client client = ClientBuilder.GetServiceObject();

    while (true)
    {
         Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0,1);
         client.BeginTest(BeginTestCallback, new AsyncState
         {
             Client = client,
             Semaphore = semaphore
         });

         semaphore.WaitOne();   
    }   
}

private void BeginTestCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    try
    {
        AsyncState state = asyncResult.AsyncState as AsyncState;

        Client client = state.Client;
        Semaphore semaphore = state.Semaphore;

        Client.EndTest(asyncResult);    

        semaphore.Release();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Will catch the exception here because of Client.EndTest(asyncResult) in the first example
        Debug.Assert(false, e.Message);
    }
}
```

we know that the callback is called within a thread from the .net Threadpool.

If I call AsyncTest() this way :

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AsyncTest());
```

it means that AsyncTest will run in a thread from the .net Threadpool.
In this case, everything will work as expected without exception.

However, if I start a Thread this way :

```
ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(() => AsyncTest());
Thread t = new Thread(ts);
t.Start();
```

It will do random TimeoutException on the "SendTimeout" even if I put it at 10 minutes. When I check wireshark, it will randomly go from I do not even see a Syn to we only send the soap header and close the connection (only when it timeouts).

Note that I am running 10 threads doing 30 requests per seconds. It may take up to one minute to fail on the second example.

Why?

Comment: Could it be that when using the ThreadPool, you only have ### many concurrent connections?  This would be limited at the server-side portion of your WCF service.  And when you are using your own threads, you are in fact running more concurrently and running into this ### max limit.  Just a theory, but worth investigating.

Comment: How do we know the callback is being called on a thread pool thread.  None of the code you've posted does that.  It's hard to tell why things do anything a certain way without all the code.

Comment: *IF* `BeginTest` is asynchronous as you've alluded to (callback is called on a thread pool thread) then why would you invoke `BeginTest` from either a thread pool thread or a non-thread pool thread anyway?

Comment: Chris O: I do not control the servers and when I run 10 threads, the requests on each threads are on 10 different servers made by different people.

Peter : 1)I think this is how WCF works? anyway I checked the callstack when breaking in the callback.
2) This example is simplified, in my real project we call the BeginTest from CCR (which use the CCR threadpool) and less frequently, but we still have the problem after a few hours.

Comment: Chris : Also, it is not the server that close the connection, but the client